# Using jamon in Spring

Tags: spring, jamon

I am trying to use Jamon in my spring app to but i don't see any messages here's my context.xml definitions for jamon .

```
<bean id="jamonMonitoringAspectInterceptor" class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor">
    <property name="loggerName" value="JamonLogger"/>
    <property name="trackAllInvocations" value="true"></property>
    <property name="useDynamicLogger" value="true"></property>
</bean>

<aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="jamonMonitoringPointcut"
                    expression="execution(* com.myorg.somepack.networkapi.websocket.WebSocketService.*(..))"/>

            <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="jamonMonitoringPointcut" 
                    advice-ref="jamonMonitoringAspectInterceptor"/>
</aop:config>
```

I don't get any exception and everything is working fine but I don't see jamon working.

Answer (score 0):

Specify either `loggerName` or `useDynamicLogger` flag, but not both in your `jamonMonitoringAspectInterceptor` bean. See javadoc [here](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AbstractTraceInterceptor.html#setLoggerName%28java.lang.String%29).

Also verify that the logger level is set to `TRACE` and jamonapi dependency is included in your project.